# I want to track when an image is downloaded from Colorbox overlay

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I see some alerts in the sample files that I thought might work but down' see an onDownload and wondered if there is a workaround.

Specifically when a logged-in user with an active SessionID right-clicks on an image within the Colorbox overlay I want to capture the sessionID, the group and the image that was downloaded.

current example

```
$(".aw14image").colorbox({rel:'aw14image', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
$('a.aw14title').colorbox({title:function () {
                return "To download full set, " + "click here!".link("goes to a tracked download page for the collection of images");
                }});
```

have linked html elements

```
<a class="aw14image aw14title" style="visibility:hidden;"href="productimages/Alienware_14_Laptop/02.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: Just because there's a right click doesn't mean that there will be a download. A better option is to add your own method for downloading so it's easier to distinguish from a possible download to an absolute download.  Adding a link over the image like a download button in the top corner and having that download but call your tracking function is a better option than logging right clicks.

Comment: You may use Google analytics' [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy) to track downloads.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Evan and Sheikh. I did a few things to be able to track the image download. First disabled the ability to right-click and save the cboxphoto: $('.cboxPhoto').live("contextmenu", function(e) {
       return false;
    });

Comment: Then added $(this).data('image-link') to the title function: $('a.aw14title').colorbox({title:function () {
       return  $(this).data('image-link') +  "<br>To download full set, " + "click here!".link("/ASP/PageStat.asp?VID=45&amp;Page=Resources_Images_Alienware_14Laptop_ZIP&amp;Link=http://www.liveandlearndell.com/resources/productimages/Alienware 14 Laptop.zip");
    }});

Comment: Last added data-image-link to the image link...  ,data-image-link="<a href='http://dev.liveandlearndell.com/ASP/PageStat.asp?VID=45&amp;Page=Resources_Images_Alienware_14Laptop_02&amp;Link=http://www.liveandlearndell.com/resources/productimages/Alienware_14_Laptop/02.jpg' target='_blank'>Click here to open image in new window for download</a>" lot of code to add to each collection element and wanted to know if there is a dynamic way to ID the current cboxphoto elment and image path

Answer (score 0):

Great suggestions!

First I disabled the cboxPhoto element from right click to download:

```
//Disable Right Click on photo to save
        $('.cboxPhoto').live("contextmenu", function(e) {
        return false;
        });
```

Then added the $(this).data('image-link') to the Title links I already had to download a ZIP of the image collection:

```
//Define the Title links
        $('a.aw14title').colorbox({title:function () {
        return  $(this).data('image-link') +  "<br>To download full set, " + "click here!".link   ("/ASP/PageStat.asp?VID=45&amp;Page=Resources_Images_Alienware_14Laptop_ZIP&amp;Link=http://www.liveandlearndell.com/resources/productimages/Alienware 14 Laptop.zip");
                }});
```

Last I added the unique download path and tracking  to the data-image-link of each image object in the collection:

```
data-image-link=" Right click to &#8220;save as&#8221; <a href='http://dev.liveandlearndell.com/ASP/PageStat.asp?VID=45&amp;Page=Resources_Images_Alienware_14Laptop_01&amp;Link=http://www.liveandlearndell.com/resources/productimages/Alienware_14_Laptop/01.jpg' target='_blank'>click here</a> or open in new window to &#8220;save as&#8221; image download"
```

it works but is clunky in that it requires each image object to be coded with the specific data-image-link... Question2:

Can I use a dynamic method to identify the current image name and download path displayed in the colorbox overlay?